# Get version of a Cocoapods-based library

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I publish my Swift library as a CocoaPod. For debugging purposes, I want to print my Pod's version string (spec.version) to console.

The following code works:

```
print(Bundle.init(for: MyClass.self)
    .object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "CFBundleShortVersionString"))
```

... but it looks hackish, so maybe there's a better way.